# Do we substitute the point in question in direction vector for parametric equation of 3d vectors?

Tags: calculus, vectors

To get the parametric equation of a line, we need the position vector and the direction vector.

Let $\vec r(t) = t^2 \hat i + (2 - \ln t)\hat j$; and the point $t_0$ be $1.$

First we find the position vectors, 
$r(1) = \hat i + 2 \hat j$;
then we need to find the direction vector of the tangent, to find which we differentiate r(t).
$$r'(t) = 2t \hat i + \frac{-1}{t} \hat j$$

Then it's just a matter of adding the two,

$$x = 1 + 2t$$
$$y = 2 - \frac{1}{t}$$

But this answer is wrong. According to my book, the value for $x$ and $y$ would be $1 + 2t$ and $2 - t$, meaning they substituted $t = 1$ in the direction vectors. My question is, shouldn't they have not done that? direction vectors extend for all points of t, why just put in a point (albeit one that is asked for in the question) in the direction vector?

Sorry if I can't make it clear, the **question** is: Find the parametric equation of the line tangent to the graph of $r(t)$ at the point where $t = t_0$
a) $\vec r(t) = t^2\hat i + (2-\ln t)\hat j; t_0 = 1$

Comment: The general equation of a line is $\vec a(t) = \vec a_0 + t\vec v$, where $\vec a_0$ is the (constant) position vector and $\vec v$ is the (constant) direction vector.  For the line tangent to a curve $\vec r(t)$ evaluated at $t=1$, the position vector will be $\vec r(1)$ (because this describes where $\vec r$ is at $t=1$) and the direction vector will be $\vec r'(1)$ (because this describes the "slope" of $\vec r$ at $t=1$).  Plug those into the general equation to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The line is described by $x=x_0 + x'(1)t$ and $y=y_0+y'(1)t$

$r_0=(x_0, y_0)=(x(1), y(1))=(1,2)$

$x'(1)=2$ and $y'(1)=-1$

Therefore, $x=1+2t$ and $y=2-t$

Comment: Why would you subsititute the 1 in x' and y' ?

Comment: You substitute $1$ because a line has constant direction and you want the direction of the tangent line at $t_0=1$.